# Bug? "Users with less than 100 reputation ..."

Tags: bug, status-completed

Not sure if that's the right place to report this.

I've got 100 reputation on cooking SE. However, when I try to post two questions within 20 minutes, it says "users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes; try again later". Clearly, that's either a bug in the "Ask Question" module or merely in the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

right, this was a fencepost error. You needed 1 more rep. I changed `>` to `>=` there.